# How to get all my directories and sub directories full path in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have base path (for example `C:\`) and i want to get all my `directories` and sub `directories` full path (not only the names).
Currently i have this:

```
path = 'c:\'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        print(os.path.dirname(dir))
```

This one for example:

```
print(os.path.abspath(dir))
```

Return the current `.py` scripy folder + the current folder (dir)

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `os.path.join` to join the sub-directory names with the path of their parent directories:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, dir)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.abspath` and  `os.path.join` for this task:

```
import os
path = 'c:\'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        print (os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, dir)))
```